# Stacked bar chart in python- When to use and what details to use

Tags: pandas

I'm a novice in python and pandas and I'm learning by solving examples in Kaggle. I have taken up the most famous example, 'Titanic'.

here is the specific question
I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart, I want to see survived and died stacked on the male & female bars.

this is the code I have written, I'm not getting the stack but I'm getting different bars

```
Data.groupby('Sex').Survived.value_counts().plot.bar(stacked = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Matplotlib library to do this. Your line also uses the same library implicitly but using Matplotlib separately will give you much more control over your graphs. You can split the data into 2 data frames and plot them.

```
import Matplotlib.pyplot as plt

maleDataSet = Data[Data["SEX" == "M"]]
femaleDataSet = Data[Data["SEX" == "F"]]

plt.bar(0, male.Survived.count())
plt.bar(0, female.Survived.count(), bottom=male.Height.count())
plt.show()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did a further deepdive into my code and found that the data was not getting unstacked.